# Can I travel freely (no COVID-19 restrictions) within Schengen Area after formally entering a Schengen country?

Tags: air-travel, schengen, covid-19

Does anyone have answer to this question? For example: an US traveler (fully vaccinated and tested negative within 72 hour from departure) fly into Rome and go through custom successfully. He/she then continue the trip to Paris after a few days, and fly to Madrid again later. Does this US traveler needed to take any COVID-19 test again to go from Rome to Paris and Paris to Marid? Or he/she can travel freely without having to do anything?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I travel freely (no COVID-19 restrictions) within Schengen Area after formally entering a Schengen country?

No. See https://reopen.europa.eu/en for the requirements of each country.

E.g. currently for France https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/FRA/7001:

> Non-vaccinated travellers arriving from Spain, Portugal, Cyprus, Malta, the Netherlands and Greece must present a negative PCR or antigenic test taken less than 24 hours before departure.

If you're vaccinated you should be fine in most (all?) EU countries, but this sometimes depends on which vaccine you had, and when you had it. E.g. Sinovac doesn't work for Italy https://reopen.europa.eu/en/map/ITA/7001

Comment: I’d also note that restrictions are generally more lax if you drive your own vehicle.

Comment: @JonathanReez Thanks good point the requirements indeed depend on how one enters the country.

Comment: @JonathanReez it’s usually not the restrictions which are more lax, just their enforcement…

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Thank you. The map is very helpful. I'll keep checking on the map for updated requirements. One thing I'd like to point out is that France issues their version of EU COVID-19 Digital Certificate to non-citizen if you have plan to travel to France soon. Here's the website just in case anyone needs it: https://www.demarches-simplifiees.fr/commencer/passe-sanitaire-etrangers

Answer (score 2):

There are even restrictions or requirements within a single country.

For instance, in France, any “long distance” bus or train travel (i.e. not commuter bus or train) requires you to have a valid “pass sanitaire”, which is proof of full vaccination, of a recent negative test, or of recovery (within a given time range).

You must have the recognised QR Code-like barcode to allow scanning by operators. So the first step for you is to convert your foreign vaccination certificate into EU format. A number of countries, including France, have a procedure for that. Note however that in general, only vaccines used in the EU are recognised.

In France you’ll also need the pass sanitaire for restaurants, museums, exhibitions, and larger malls and stores.